# How to put drywall over garage uneven concrete wall?

Tags: drywall, concrete, garage

I would like to make my garage wall a bit "smoother". And now I think about using drywall to cover the bare concrete. However the concrete is very uneven with at least 1 inch of concrete sticking out like in the corner below

[image]

(Sorry this pic turned side way)

[image]

The wall has several "lines" with metal wires sticking out. I could cut the wires but it will be hard to "sand" or cut the concrete.

What are your suggestion? Or should I "frame" 2x2 or something like that with plywood on the outside then?

Comment: Think about this *carefully and at length* before doing something to cover this. Framing and plywood are fuel for fire and harborage for bugs and rodents.

Comment: Do you need or want shelves along this wall? This would obscure the imperfections in the wall. The shelves could be free standing or could be hung from the wall, e.g., elfa wall hung shelving. What is on the other side of this wall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when drywalling over masonry walls you install furring strips.  Furring strips are verital strips of wood to which you can attach the drywall (or plywood or whatever you want).  You can easily position and / or notch the furring strips so that the face of the strips comes out level.  You can use lumber as small as 1x2s, it's also common to use 2x4's.  There are also metal furring strips available.

Heavier furring strips are better for attaching shelves etc.  Sometimes by the time it's all said and done, you're better off just framing a hollow wall in front of the masonry wall.  This way you can leave a little breathing room between the wall and the masonry, and you have a full stud depth for insulation, electrical, etc.

[image: installing furring strips]